# TCP connection socket

Tags: python, tcpclient, tcpserver

I wrote a simple TCP connection socket the server print the sentence from a client , but I got a wrong result anyone explain what is the problem, please.

another question is what is the correct way to print the value of variable and sentence in python 3

the server code is

```
from socket import *


serverPort = 12000

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

serverSocket.bind(('', 12000))

serverSocket.listen(1)

connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

while 1:
        sentence = connectionSocket.recv(10240)
        print ("from server", sentence)

serverSocket.close();
```

and client code is

```
from socket import *

serverName = '127.0.0.1'
serverPort = 12000

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverName,serverPort))
sentence = input('Input lowercase sentense:') 
clientSocket.send(sentence.encode())
clientSocket.close()
```

the result is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv0vB.png)

Answer (score 0):

you are getting that weird print because you are not checking data from client.
As a workaround you can check whether the data sent from client is empty or have value. If it have value print it and otherwise don't do anything.

Please let me know if you need any code reference or something extra.

```
if sentense:
  print sentense
```

Comment: meanwhile you can also use python string formation for formatting the string returned from client. :)